# Whichever versus Which

Tags: grammar

David didn't know which was his.
David didn't know whichever was his.

Which is which? It sounds like the two words add little or no different meaning to the sentences, but which one is more correct?

Comment: Which" is correct. "Whichever" is only used in a certain kind of interrogative like "Whichever one you buy him, he won't be satisfied", and in relative constructions: "We bought whichever tickets were available".

Answer (score 1):

"Which" and "Whichever" do not mean the same thing.  "Whichever you pick" actually means something more like "any one that you pick".  Examples:

> When you rescue a cat or a dog from the animal shelter, don't be too worried about picking one.  **Whichever** you choose will turn out to be a great pet.
>
> When she came to a fork in the path, **whichever** way she went seemed to lead her deeper into the forest instead of leading her out.

In your example, it doesn't really work without more context:

> David knew that **whichever** dog he picked would be his forever.